# How to default-initialize a struct containing an array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, struct, rust, initializer

What is the recommended way to declare a struct that contains an array, and then create a zero-initialized instance?

Here is the struct:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Histogram {
    sum: u32,
    bins: [u32; 256],
}
```

and the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u32; 256]: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     bins: [u32; 256],
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `[u32; 256]`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <[T; 14] as std::default::Default>
            <&'a [T] as std::default::Default>
            <[T; 22] as std::default::Default>
            <[T; 7] as std::default::Default>
          and 31 others
  = note: required by `std::default::Default::default`
```

If I attempt to add the missing initializer for the array:

```
impl Default for [u32; 256] {
    fn default() -> [u32; 255] {
        [0; 256]
    }
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
 --> src/lib.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     impl Default for [u32; 256] {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
  |
  = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Rust uses `macro_rules!` to generate `Default` for arrays up to length 32. But now that const generics are stable, one would assume that at some point they'll go back and `impl<const N: usize, T: Default> Default for [T; N]`. Unfortunately, for the moment this is blocked on `[T; 0]` not requiring `T: Default` while `[T; N]` does for `N >= 1`, and there is no “const specialization” yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rust does not implement `Default` for all arrays because it does not have non-type polymorphism. As such, `Default` is only implemented for a handful of sizes.

You can, however, implement a default for *your type*:

```
impl Default for Histogram {
    fn default() -> Histogram {
        Histogram {
            sum: 0,
            bins: [0; 256],
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I would contend that implementing `Default` for `u32` is fishy to start with; why `0` and not `1`? or `42`? There is no good answer, so no obvious default really.*

Comment: I only got on Default because Zero is labeled as deprecated in the standard library.  In the absence of a ~Zero trait, I'd argue that fixed size arrays are more likely to be used in vector-vector addition than anything else, and the zero vector is the identity vector for addition and is a more natural choice for default.  But this is some serious bikeshedding we're doing here :)

Comment: Hi, will this cause a big cost? I am a new learner, and think the `[0;256]` will be firstly created and initialized in one place of the stack/heap, and then *move* into the `Histogram.bins`. Thus the big array is moved which consists of copying and dropping. Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n: As far as the language is concerned, you are right. Once the optimizer gets its teeth on the code however, things will change _a lot_. First of all, there's no need to `Drop` the array, because none of its elements require a `Drop`. Secondly, it's actually likely that the compiler will just write 0 all over `Histogram` without initializing the elements piecemeal. And thirdly, depending on the caller, it may never actually materialize the struct, and maybe not even materialize the array... optimizing compilers can make astonishing transformations, if given the opportunity.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you can't do this, you will need to implement `Default` for your structure yourself:

```
struct Histogram {
    sum: u32,
    bins: [u32; 256],
}

impl Default for Histogram {
    #[inline]
    fn default() -> Histogram {
        Histogram {
            sum: 0,
            bins: [0; 256],
        }
    }
}
```

Numeric types have nothing to do with this case, it's more like problems with fixed-size arrays. They still need generic numerical literals to support this kind of things natively.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir!  Matthieu gave the same answer faster, but yours has the inline.  I'd accept both if I could!

Comment: Yeah, I pressed submit button just at the moment when the other answer has appeared :) That's ok, everything is fair :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure to initialize every field with zero, this would work:

```
impl Default for Histogram {
    fn default() -> Histogram {
        unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, at the time of writing, support for fixed-length arrays is still being hashed out in the standard library:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/7622

Answer (score 1):

If the array type is not `Copy`, the answer by @MatthieuM. won't work. In this case, instead of specifying each element explicitly (which is tedious and even impossible for generic array), you can use [`std::array::from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```rust
impl Default for Histogram {
    fn default() -> Histogram {
        Histogram {
            sum: Default::default(),
            bins: std::array::from_fn(|_| Default::default()),
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it using [`array::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#method.map), if you prefer:

```rust
impl Default for Histogram {
    fn default() -> Histogram {
        Histogram {
            sum: Default::default(),
            bins: [(); 256].map(|()| Default::default()),
        }
    }
}
```